# Making Finder use embedded JPG thumbnail for preview

Tags: finder, preview, spotlight, heif

I know that macOS has a crippled support of HEIF files, because it can't open those with a bit depth > 8 bits:

[Why can't Preview Export 16-bit HEIC images?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420299/)

Actually I have 16 bits HEIF files that macOS does not properly handle: blank previews in the Finder and not rendered by Preview (they are rendered as a blue blob). Files are fine since I can open them with Gimp.

Now I've tried to embed JPEG EXIF thumbnails within them (thumbnails are properly created because I can re-extract them with `exiftool`) expecting at least the Finder to use them, but nothing changed. Is it possible to force it in some way? I suppose this has to do with Spotlight, but I really don't know it enough.

As a reference, this is the command I used to convert HEIF files from TIFF:

`convert "file.tiff[0]" -quality 90 "file.heif"`

And this is the command used to embed thumbnails:

`convert -thumbnail 2000x2000 -quality 70 -profile srgb file.heif jpeg:- | exiftool  "-ThumbnailImage<=-" file.heif`

`convert` is from ImageMagick of course.

I'm running macOS Monterey 12.6.7.

Thanks.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, those previews aren't pulled from the meta data.  Instead, they are generated by [QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing). From the way I understand it works is that as long as there's an extension, Finder and Spotlight will generate the Thumbnail.  If not, it gets a generic icon.

Comment: It is a thing I wasn't really looking into. Thanks, now I know where to investigate further.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/providing_thumbnails_of_your_custom_file_types